# Anaconda and package installation (pydicom)

Tags: python, package, conda, pydicom

I have the following problem. 
I have tried to install the pydicom package in python 2.7 using the following command (windows, anaconda setup):

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydicom
```

everything seems to work fine, the package seems to be installed.
I type

```
conda list
```

and in the list I see

```
pydicom                   0.9.8                     <pip>
```

I open spyder, or pycharm, type

```
import pydicom
```

and I get

> ImportError: No module named pydicom

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. I went through http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html and everything seems to be fine.

Please assist.

Comment: Use a virtualenv. In PyCharm add the reference to this virtualenv.

Comment: Does it work with `python -c "import pydicom"`?

Comment: Also, it's weird that it says `<pip>` if you installed from conda-forge. Maybe try: `conda uninstall pydicom`, `pip uninstall pydicom` (repeat until no package found), and then `conda install -c conda-forge pydicom`?

Comment: After you do @ostrokach's suggestion, and confirm that `pydicom` is working when using the python in your command prompt, then you probably need to adjust the python that your pycharm/spyder is using.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `0.9.8`, you [actually need `import dicom`](http://pydicom.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#using-pydicom) rather than `import pydicom`.

Due to this confusion, it will be `import pydicom` in version `1.0.0` and later.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you either update Python Version > 3.0, so that the output for conda list shows something like this:

```
(pip install pydicom)

pydicom                   1.0.2                     <pip>
python                    3.6.4                h6538335_1
```

Now import using:

```
import pydicom #Preferable
```

==========================================================

Or install dicom instead of pydicom using:

```
(pip install pydicom-0.9.8)

pydicom                   0.9.8                    <pip>
python                    2.7.0                h6538335_1
```

And then, import using:

```
import dicom
```

However, I strongly suggest that you install pydicom instead of dicom, since it is the upgraded version.